# Using Microsift Word/Outlook for content publishing to Wordpress

Tags: plugins, formatting, xml-rpc

I am tasked with building an tool to allow users to publish to Wordpress from their PC using MS Word and Outlook. I know, completely defeat the purpose of having Wordpress, but the basic requirement are:

1. Format must be preserved, including images
2. Providing an interface for categorizing and tagging the document
3. Does not involve the WP web UI.  (Users insist on using Word as the publishing tool)
4. Workflow should be simple as possible, ie invoke in Word, select
   categories/tags, publish.

After doing some research, I think this could be achieved by creating an VBA macro that saves Word to html format, and sending it via http to wordpress XMLRPC

However, I haven't quite work out how to include the images, and how to keep the category from Wordpress and the macro in sync.

I would like to hear from anyone who have experience in this and suggestion on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it but...

If you are not going to use multisite, then Wordpress has a *Post via e-mail* feature setup under Settings > Writing. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email

An alternative might be to get them to use **Windows Live Writer**, which would give the users a familiar mircrosoft interface. See: http://explore.live.com/windows-live-essentials-help-center?T1=t7

Comment: Thanks, Live Writer worked out to be an great option that has all the feature I am looking for out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is built-in functionality for Word 2007 and later. [Here's a tutorial for how to set it up within Word, to publish using XML-RPC](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/home/from-word-to-blog-in-no-time-flat-HA010356394.aspx).

(Note: for stand-alone WordPress, just use `[wordpress url]/xmlrpc.php` as the blog post URL, and the username/password of the WordPress user as whom you wish to post from Word, and be sure that XML-RPC is *enabled*, via `Dashboard -> Settings -> Writing -> Remote Publishing`.)